# how do i filter a column with multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

how do i filter a column col1 with multiple values

```
select * from table where col1=2 and col1=4 and  userID='740b9738-63d2-67ff-ba21-801b65dd0ae1'
```

i tired

```
select * from table where col1=2 or col1=4 and  userID='740b9738-63d2-67ff-ba21-801b65dd0ae1'
```

the result of both queries is incorrect

the first one gives zero results 
second one gives 3 results

the correct is 2 results

the sql will run against the sqlite db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` is evaluated before `OR`, so your query is equivalent to:

```
select * 
from table 
where col1=2 or (col1=4 and  userID='740b9738-63d2-67ff-ba21-801b65dd0ae1')
```

You need to explicitly group the conditions when mixing `AND` and `OR`:

```
select * 
from table 
where (col1=2 or col1=4) and  userID='740b9738-63d2-67ff-ba21-801b65dd0ae1'
```